# Best crypto for hashing payload post data

Tags: javascript, cryptography, bcrypt, cryptojs

I am in no means a crypto guy and am struggling with all the different options out there.

I currently have a mobile app and API that will have a private key. I want to be able to hash the payload data on the mobile app with this key as a 'salt' per say. Then send the payload and hash to the API, the API will then hash the payload data with the private key and confirm the values are the same.

I was originally looking at bcrypt but they create random salts which would not work in my case. Looking for any suggestions..

Mobile app is using Titanium Appcelerator so Javascript and website is PHP.

Thanks

Comment: In this case ups could just use an HMAC using SHA256.

Comment: What do you want to protect against? What's your threat model?

Comment: We did a basic pen test and parameter manipulation was the main issue we are trying to fix. Figure a basic hash with the private key would allow us to validate the data before processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code), and sha256 would be a good choice of hash function to use along with it.